# Keep checkbox checked even after page refresh?

Tags: jquery

I have written a `if` condition for checking a checkbox:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (this.id == "internships" && this.checked) {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('job/internships'); ?>";
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('job/internships'); ?>";
    }
});
```

Now I want to make sure that even after page refresh the checkbox does not change its state unless I/user do so. How can I do that?

Comment: pass a get parameter with the url and do the rest based on the passed value

Comment: You need to store the state of the checkbox somewhere. You could use a URL parameter, localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies or a server-side database. Choice is yours.

Comment: can u show me how to do it with localstorage in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to generate the checkbox with the `checked` property already set. 
Following your code style, it would be something like

```
<?php
// prepare a string to be inserted.
// it will be either empty, or a nonempty "checked" attribute
$shouldBeChecked = is_this_the_internship_page() ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>
```

And then...

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo $shouldBeChecked; ?> >
```

if I remember PHP correctly :-)

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Also, your JS contains two identical redirections at the moment of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of localStorage

**JS**

```
$('#check').on('click', function(){

  if(localStorage.getItem("checkedbox") == 'true') {
    $(this).prop(checked, 'false');
    localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", 'false');

  }
  else {
    $(this).prop(checked, 'true');
     localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", 'true');
  }

})
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "checkbox" id="check"/>
```